# failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: hcsshim::ProcessBaseLayer \\?\D:\docker\windowsfilter\...: Access is denied

Tags: .net, docker, docker-image, docker-pull

I,m trying to pull image. It successfully downloads, but "Access Denied" errors occurs after extract. I have full folder access to "D:/docker"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Docker probably not allowed by Virus Protection. if you use Microsoft Antivirus Check your notifications. You can allow Docker if you have the rights to do so.